# Which algorithm could I use for shortest path with distinct sets of must-pass nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph, set, shortest-path

I'm not sure of the name of this problem so haven't really been able to research it. I have a complete weighted graph with a start and end node and n distinct sets of nodes (lets call them red, blue and green), each with m member nodes.

I need to find the shortest path from start to end and must pass through exactly one red, one blue and one green node; is there an algorithm for this?

An extension would be that I need to find the shortest path while visiting blue first, then green, then red (again, exactly once each); is there one for this?

Comment: I don't think there is a specific algorithm for this. Shortest path algorithms tend to explore all paths and with some memoization you could keep track of which paths meet your must-pass criteria. Among those meeting your criteria you would sort and choose the shortest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension part seems easier.

Assuming every node has a colour (is this true?) all you need to do if to delete edges that would violate the desired colour sequence.

For example, delete all edges leaving the start, except those that go to a blue node.  Similarly, delete all edges leaving a blue node, except those that go to a green node.

Then you can simply run a standard shortest path algorithm (e.g. Dijkstra) on the reduced graph.

If the number of colours is not too great, then you can adapt the same algorithm to solve the original problem.  The idea is to find the shortest path (using the algorithm described above) for each permutation of the colours.